# How to change (sub)key usage of a PGP key?

Tags: key-management, pgp, gnupg, key-usage

`gpg2` generates keys with one or several of the (S)igning, (E)ncryption, (C)ertification usages set. However, e.g. Enigmail creates a primary key also set for (A)uthentication, which GnuPG then shows. How can this be set/modified using `gpg2`? I can't find any command in `--edit-keys`, and when I create a subkey the only options are

```
 Please select what kind of key you want:  
   (3) DSA (sign only)  
   (4) RSA (sign only)  
   (5) Elgamal (encrypt only)  
   (6) RSA (encrypt only)
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Since GnuPG 2.2.6 there's a hidden [key-edit subcommand "change-usage"](https://dev.gnupg.org/T3970) which does exactly that. [Relevant commit.](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=commit;h=9b28b82e7c40d1eacc446d5932cd613c56378ed8)

Let's try this subcommand with a test key. Let's create one first:

```
mkdir /tmp/gpg-change-usage
chmod 700 /tmp/gpg-change-usage
gpg --homedir /tmp/gpg-change-usage --quick-generate-key someone@example.com rsa4096 cert 1d
```

Now notice that this new key is a certification only primary key.

```
$ gpg --homedir /tmp/gpg-change-usage -k
/tmp/gpg-change-usage/pubring.kbx
---------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2019-04-04 [C] [expires: 2019-04-05]
      987BE3D9CF90B1C912A165734EBF4D26A937DE4C
uid           [ultimate] someone@example.com
```

Changing usage is a simple as this:

```
$ gpg --homedir /tmp/gpg-change-usage --edit-key someone@example.com 
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.12; Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Secret key is available.

sec  rsa4096/4EBF4D26A937DE4C
     created: 2019-04-04  expires: 2019-04-05  usage: C   
     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
[ultimate] (1). someone@example.com

gpg> change-usage
Changing usage of the primary key.

Possible actions for a RSA key: Sign Certify Encrypt Authenticate 
Current allowed actions: Certify 

   (S) Toggle the sign capability
   (E) Toggle the encrypt capability
   (A) Toggle the authenticate capability
   (Q) Finished

Your selection? s

Possible actions for a RSA key: Sign Certify Encrypt Authenticate 
Current allowed actions: Sign Certify 

   (S) Toggle the sign capability
   (E) Toggle the encrypt capability
   (A) Toggle the authenticate capability
   (Q) Finished

Your selection? q

sec  rsa4096/4EBF4D26A937DE4C
     created: 2019-04-04  expires: 2019-04-05  usage: SC  
     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate
[ultimate] (1). someone@example.com

gpg> save
```

Notice now that our key gained signing capability.

```
$ gpg --homedir /tmp/gpg-change-usage -k
/tmp/gpg-change-usage/pubring.kbx
---------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2019-04-04 [SC] [expires: 2019-04-05]
      987BE3D9CF90B1C912A165734EBF4D26A937DE4C
uid           [ultimate] someone@example.com
```

That's it!

Answer (score 9):

In order to *add* a new subkey with specific usages, start `gpg2` with the `--expert` switch. Then the options are

```
Please select what kind of key you want:
   (3) DSA (sign only)
   (4) RSA (sign only)
   (5) Elgamal (encrypt only)
   (6) RSA (encrypt only)
   (7) DSA (set your own capabilities)
   (8) RSA (set your own capabilities)
Your selection?
```

Where the last two methods allow toggling each of S, E, A individually. C is only possible for a primary key, the usage of which you can also set with `gpg2 --expert --gen-key`. I don't know of any way to modify the usage field at a later point however.